# Configure Lightdm (GTK) for last saved or a default user and focus on password?

Tags: lightdm

I've looked at the man pages and the configuration files but found nothing (but maybe I'm missing something). I see only many options for autologin.

From a few googles I've read that the KDE version does work this way, but I would like to continue using the GTK version.

**update**

I still haven't found a solution and sometime I come back to this issue, looking around have seen some screenshots of `lightdm-gtk-greeter` that support themes and a popup menu for the user list.

I'm surely missing something in the configuration or need to install some package.

I'm using openbox not gnome, below a picture of my poor greeter.

**howto make it remember last user and focus to the password?**

[image]

**update 2**

I'm using a GNU/Debian/unstable (jessie/sid)

here some details of the installed `lightdm*`

```
$ dpkg -l "*lightdm*" | grep ^ii
ii  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 1.10.0-3     i386         simple display manager (gobject library)
ii  lightdm                1.10.0-3     i386         simple display manager
ii  lightdm-gtk-greeter    1.8.4-1      i386         simple display manager (GTK+ greeter)

$ apt-cache show lightdm-gtk-greeter|grep Homepage
Homepage: https://launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

and a debug log (launched from desktop eventually I can add the version from `/var/log`)

```
$ /usr/sbin/lightdm --test-mode --debug
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /home/alex/.cache/lightdm/log/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.10.0, UID=1000 PID=477
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Running in user mode
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using Xephyr for X servers
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module surfaceflinger
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating greeter session
[+0.01s] WARNING: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading user config from /etc/lightdm/users.conf
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User alex added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User trustno1 added
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Could not run plymouth --ping: Failed to execute child process "plymouth" (No such file or directory)
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display
[+0.01s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Logging to /home/alex/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Writing X server authority to /home/alex/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
[+0.06s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Launching X Server
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Launching process 482: /usr/bin/Xephyr :1 -seat seat0 -auth /home/alex/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1 -nolisten tcp
[+0.08s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
/bin/rm: impossibile rimuovere "/var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm": Permesso negato
[+0.16s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 482
[+0.16s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Got signal from X server :1
[+0.16s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Connecting to XServer :1
[+0.16s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.16s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.16s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'alex'

** (process:487): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Seat: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/alex
[+0.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Logging to /home/alex/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1-greeter.log
[+0.26s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Greeter connected version=1.10.0
[+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Greeter start authentication
[+0.79s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=504: Started with service 'lightdm', username '(null)'
[+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=504: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Got signal 2 from process 0
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Caught Interrupt signal, shutting down
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping display server
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 482
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping session
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Sending SIGTERM
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping session
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Session pid=504: Sending SIGTERM
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Session pid=504: Terminated with signal 2
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Session: Failed during authentication
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Session pid=487: Terminated with signal 2
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Process 482 exited with return value 0
[+3.23s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: X server stopped
[+3.23s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Removing X server authority /home/alex/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server stopped
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopped
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+3.23s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 0
```

here the `/etc` config files

```
$ grep -v ^# /etc/lightdm/*.conf
/etc/lightdm/keys.conf:[keyring]
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:[LightDM]
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:[SeatDefaults]
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:greeter-hide-users=true
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:greeter-allow-guest=false
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:[XDMCPServer]
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:[VNCServer]
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:[greeter]
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:background=/usr/share/images/desktop-base/login-background.svg
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:theme-name=Adwaita
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:xft-antialias=true
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:xft-hintstyle=hintfull
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:xft-rgba=rgb
/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf:show-indicators=~language;~session;~power
/etc/lightdm/users.conf:[UserAccounts]
/etc/lightdm/users.conf:minimum-uid=500
/etc/lightdm/users.conf:hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
/etc/lightdm/users.conf:hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

**update 3**

I've check version 1.1.6-2/stable with no results.

Installed `accountsservice`.

(in the while `lightdm-gtk-greeter` dist-upgraded to 1.8.5-1)

below `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf`

commented out are values as coming from the Debian installation, I changed them (but seem they are overwritten by `/etc/lightdm/lighdm.conf`)

```
[SeatDefaults]
#greeter-session=lightdm-greeter
#greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
greeter-hide-users=false
session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

also changed `greeter-hide-users` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, the popup menu now appear, it show `others...`, user `alex`is bold as if it is the current or default but below the popup there's still the user input text field with focus and empty (I'll update the screenshot and the test/debug log later).

Comment: Could you clarify please? Do you want to set up auto login? Do you want lightdm to remember the last user? Or the last session?

Comment: The best would be if the last used user is remembered but a default would be fine, and the focus to the password field so that just the password is needed to login. Currently I've to type the user+password always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: (after comments)

Try to modify in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:`

```
 greeter-hide-users=true
```

in

```
 greeter-hide-users=false
```

It's seems it's needed in all lightdm `.conf` files.
It's possible you need to use
`lightdm-set-defaults [OPTION...]` to fix it.
The full options available are in the file:
`/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz` (if installed).

**update**

In Debian is important to set it in the right *section* `[]`, `[SeatDefaults]` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` should *win*, use `lightdm --show-config` to see changed settings an in which files are (relative to default values)

---

Original:
Maybe you can try to add this ppa
`ppa:lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/daily`
and install the LightDM GTK+ Greeter 1.6.0.
it seems that it solves automatically your problem [you can see here](http://smdavis.us/2013/06/03/lightdm-gtk-greeter-1-6-0-released/).

I find the ppa on this [page](https://launchpad.net/~lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/+archive/daily) of the Launchpad blog posts.

You can download directly from [here](https://launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter/1.6/1.6.0)
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @Hastur, but I think I'm already using that version even if installed from the official Debian repositories (at least same mainstream) +1 for pointing out that I missed a lot of detailes about the installation, see `update 2`

Comment: Thank you. From the 1st link you can see it's possible to select via menu the user. You have a more recent version installed.

Comment: Just an idea: try to modify /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:greeter-hide-users=true in `greeter-hide-users=**false**`.

Comment: see `update 3`, a little step forward even if seem not to solve, but I've more test to do that I cannot do right now, I'll let you know, thank you

Comment: yep, the test/debug mode from desktop is messed up, but on real boot it work :) (edit your answer)

Comment: Here you should find all the possible options `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz`. 

You can set with `lightdm-set-defaults [OPTION...]` else I suppose they can finish to be overwritten

Comment: interesting, seem both the command and the doc's conf are missing, even if dpkg -S show lightdm-set-defaults should be in the lightdm deb

Comment: I need to wait 17 hours before award the bounty, in the end all the matter was about having `greeter-hide-users=false` in all the lightdm `.conf` files, edit your answer.

Comment: Please note that for the changes to take effect you have to **reboot**, it is not enough to login/logout

Comment: @Joril Probably, when it is needed as you state, is enough (to logout and) restart `lightdm`: `sudo service lightdm restart`. (The logout is advisable to avoid process interrupted abruptly by some timeout...)

Comment: In debian 10 its enough to set attribute `greeter-hide-users=false` inside `sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf`. Then restart lightdm.service with: `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service`. After that `sudo lightdm --show-config
` show correct value.