# XFCE Login - Auto Populate Default Username

Tags: login, xfce

Is it possible to have the username auto populated at the login screen with a default users name without having `autologin` set for that user?

My search has led me to auto-login as the only option which isn't what I'm after.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using LightDM, the answer to [Configure Lightdm (GTK) for last saved or a default user and focus on password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88079/configure-lightdm-gtk-for-last-saved-or-a-default-user-and-focus-on-password) seems like it's worth a look. Note that there may also be some potentially useful info in the answer's eleven commments.

Comment: @DavidYockey Thankyou, using the link you provided I was able to hunt down the correct config parts and after a little trial and error I have been able to come up with a solution so posted it as an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to *@DavidYockey* I was able to find the solution, so will post the answer here for anyone else wanting to do this.

In `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` un-comment `greeter-hide-users` and set false if *true*  and a few lines below that set the default user you want selected using `user-session`.

[image]

**Note**: *This creates a dropdown with the user selected rather than the name inserted with a 2nd option for **other***

Comment: Just tried this in Kali Linux 2022.2 and it worked as expected. Thanks @akaBase !

Comment: You sir are a smooth pimp. Thank You!

Comment: It worked on 2022. However, it did not work on purple 2023.